# Cordova Android 6 permissions

Tags: android, cordova

I read many threads about this but I haven´t read exactly how resolve my problem. I created a mobile app with cordova and I need location the service to show a map. In my manifest I add the permisions and in  Android 5 or below works perfectly, but in Android 6 the location service fails. I read that in new Android versions Google changes permissions methods, and read that  can I simulate this with some plugins in Cordova, but fails (or maybe I don’t know how works).

I have this in my index.js

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(CurrentPosition);
};
```

And this permissions in my manifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

¿Any idea how can I run location service in Android 6?

Comment: Have you tried by giving run time permission for marshmallow? try using this following plugin `https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic` this will ask you for permission and .

Comment: This was my first idea to resolve the problem, but when I add it in plugin folder and add it config.xml when i launch the emulator no recognize the cordova.plugins.diagnostic object >:<

Answer (score 1):

If you use [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/) it takes care of initiating a permission request on Android Marshmallow and above.

You should then be able to use `navigator.geolocation` as normal.

Configuration would be something like:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" /> 
</feature>
```

In your `config.xml`. I'm not sure about the package name, on my phone at the moment.

Or just:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`

If using Cordova 5+.

Comment: Actually I use HTML5 geolocation and works in all devices except in Marshmallow. I download this package and add this in plugins folder, but  don´t know exactly work ¿I need to add some code in config.xml?

Comment: Added comment about config. As noted, I'm not sure about the exact plugin package name.

Answer (score 0):

I download cordova.plugins.diagnostic and use this code in index.js to run when app start, but don´t work.

```
 cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getLocationAuthorizationStatus(function (status) {
            switch (status) {
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.NOT_REQUESTED:
                    console.log("Permission not requested");
                    break;
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
                    console.log("Permission denied");
                    break;
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(CurrentPosition);
                    console.log("Permission granted always");
                    break;
                case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED_WHEN_IN_USE:
                    console.log("Permission granted only when in use");
                    break;
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.error("The following error occurred: " + error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `AnroidManifest.xml` and change `android:targetSdkVersion` to 22

```
android:targetSdkVersion="22"
```